# How to set visual studio setup and deployment release location for multiple projects

Tags: setup-deployment

I have several different services in separate VS solutions that I want to create a single image setup file in a particular location. I can set the Releases (Setup) tab as shown:

[image]

However, if I set more than 1 solution to create a setup file (with different names) in this location they overwrite each other. I'd like to know how to set them all to write their setup files into the same release location?

Answer (score 0):

Release Location is by default set to `<ISProjectDataFolder>` which is same location as the .ism or Installshield project file however you may change it to where setup.exe or installer project output is supposed to produced.

In one installshield project you can set only one Release Location so, it is not clear how and where you set location for others?

Do you have multiple installshield projects if yes, then you should name each projects outout file a different name so they do not overwrite existing files. See this [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/j16bym)